# Relative consumption

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier, economics

I have a utility function given by,

$$U(c_1,c_2)=c^{\alpha}_1+\beta c^{\alpha}_2$$

I found that the budget constraint is,

$$c_2=m_2+\left(\frac{1+i}{1+\pi}\right)(m_1-c_1)$$

Where $m_1,m_2$ is the income in period $c_1,c_2$, and i is the interest (the person can borrow and save at the same interest, $i$).

I'm now struggling to find the 'relative consumption' in the two periods $c_2/c_1$, where $a$ and $i$ occur (I have to substitute them for $\sigma =\frac{1}{1-a}$ and $1+r≡(1+i)(1+π)$ in the following question).

I've tried using the Langragian for maximizing the utility under the budget constraint, but I am still very puzzled by this question.

Any help?

Comment: Where did you found this constraint? What is $\pi$, inflation rate?

Comment: Yes, inflation rate

Comment: It was defined at a lecture.

Comment: My lagrangian is $$V=c_1^{\alpha}+\beta c_2^{\alpha}+\left(\frac{m_2+(1+i)m_1}{p_2}-\frac{1+i}{1+\pi}c_1-c_2\right)$$

So my FOCs are

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial c_1}=\alpha c_1^{\alpha -1}-\lambda \frac{1+i}{1+\pi}$$

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial c_2}=\alpha \beta c_2^{\alpha -1}-\lambda$$

Comment: You´re derivatives are right. What is confusing me is that the price of good 2 is now involved. Have you post the whole exercise (with text)?

Comment: The price of good 2 comes from the budget restriction where inflation is taken into account. The amount of money the consumer can spend in the second period is given by $$p_2c_2=p_2m_2+(1+r)(m_1-c_1)$$

and the amount of consumption available in the second period is $$c_2=m_2+\frac{1+r}{p_2}(m_1-c_1)$$. We can now express the budget constraint in terms of the rate of inflation. We have that $p_1=1$, thus we have $$p_2=1+\pi$$ which gives us $$c_2=m_2+\frac{1+r}{1+\pi}(m_1-c_1)$$ Thus my budget is involving the price of good 2 - used in my lagrangian. 

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The exercise is in Danish. (1) I first have to find the budget constraínt. (2) Then find the consumer's relative consumption. (3) And lastly, define $\sigma =1/(1-\alpha)$ and $1+r\equiv (1+i)/(1+\pi)$ and substitute them into my solution in (2).